# How to disable automatic zoom when cursor is on main image in single product page?

Tags: javascript, css, woocommerce

I have a problem with the thumb image on the single product page. When the cursor is on the main image, the image is zoomed in. How can I disable that?

I tried the code below but it does not work.

```css
.woocommerce div.product .images a.x-img:hover {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
```

Comment: "I tried the code below but it does not work." - What do you think that code does? Sorry, but common sense says adding a border isn't going to stop things zooming in and out.

Comment: this code is copied from a website i searched this problem by google.

Comment: It's quite difficult to help you without knowing how is the image zoomed in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
.zoomContainer { display: none; }
```

Comment: ok just add this to your css : `.product-thumb:hover .product-thumb-link img.normal-thumb {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) !important;
    transform: scale(1) !important;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
}`

Comment: please click an product and when is the single product page , put the cursor on the main image . you can see that the image gets zoom in . i want to disable zoom for main image of product page .

Comment: The best answer . thank you . The problem has solved by the last code you suggested .

Comment: youre wellcome mostafa ;)